# Cannot use import statement outside a module for SetupTest.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

My **setupTest.Js** under rootDirectory

```
import {configure}  from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

My **jestConfig.js** file has the following

```
"setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"]
```

When I run my test file,I get the following error and it points to the import statement on my setupTests.js

> **Cannot use import statement outside a module**

Comment: Are you forgetting to add .babelrc file as mentioned here https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started#using-babel

Comment: Are you using typescript by chance?